# After Effects cc 2015 zoom in and out is verry fast

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-after-effects, zoom

i'm using After Effects CC 2015 Version 13.5.0.347 and Mac OS Sierra 
when i try to zoom in and out using mouse scroll its very fast 
and i cant even control it

the Same Problem recently appears with Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 V19.0.0 
When i zoom in and out using alt+Scroll

[Please Notice This youtube link](https://youtu.be/0CY-FgJq_xs) its a screen recording for the problem.
https://youtu.be/0CY-FgJq_xs

Comment: Yeh zoom scroll sucks. I don't use it, at all, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have always found zoom scroll to be a bit uncontrollable. I much prefer to use keyboard shortcuts for zooming in and out (ctrl+ for zoom in, ctrl- for zoom out).

I don't have a solution for your exact issue but I would strongly suggest keyboard shortcuts as a great alternative!